# Change the 'and' in the formatted names of the IEEE bibliography style

Tags: ieeetran

I am using the IEEEtr bibliography style format. I was wondering how we could change the 'and' string for something else in the case the publication is not in English the same way you can change the '[Online]. Available:' string before a URL.

Normally, the style will generate:

> S. Marimuthu, A. M. Kamara, D. Whitehead, P. Mativenga, L. Li, S.
>   Yang, **and** K. Cooke, “Laser stripping of TiAlN coating to
>   facilitate reuse of cutting tools,” in Proceedings of the Institution
>   of Mechanical Engineers, Part B : Journal of Engineering Manufacture,
>   vol. 225, no. 10, Aug. 2011, pp. 1851–1862.

I would like to generate automatically the following format ('et'='and' in French):

> S. Marimuthu, A. M. Kamara, D. Whitehead, P. Mativenga, L. Li, S.
>   Yang, **et** K. Cooke, “Laser stripping of TiAlN coating to facilitate
>   reuse of cutting tools,” in Proceedings of the Institution of
>   Mechanical Engineers, Part B : Journal of Engineering Manufacture,
>   vol. 225, no. 10, Aug. 2011, pp. 1851–1862.

Is there somewhere in the code where I can change de string 'and' for 'et'?

Comment: As you don' provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), I will take the risk of a guess: have you checked if the ``babel`` package will make a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to switch to `IEEEtran` rather than the very old `IEEEtr` style.

The file `IEEEtran.bst` contains the following section:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% STRING CONSTANTS %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

FUNCTION {bbl.and}{ "and" }
FUNCTION {bbl.etal}{ "et~al." }
FUNCTION {bbl.editors}{ "eds." }
FUNCTION {bbl.editor}{ "ed." }
FUNCTION {bbl.edition}{ "ed." }
FUNCTION {bbl.volume}{ "vol." }
FUNCTION {bbl.of}{ "of" }
FUNCTION {bbl.number}{ "no." }
FUNCTION {bbl.in}{ "in" }
FUNCTION {bbl.pages}{ "pp." }
FUNCTION {bbl.page}{ "p." }
FUNCTION {bbl.chapter}{ "ch." }
FUNCTION {bbl.paper}{ "paper" }
FUNCTION {bbl.part}{ "pt." }
FUNCTION {bbl.patent}{ "Patent" }
FUNCTION {bbl.patentUS}{ "U.S." }
FUNCTION {bbl.revision}{ "Rev." }
FUNCTION {bbl.series}{ "ser." }
FUNCTION {bbl.standard}{ "Std." }
FUNCTION {bbl.techrep}{ "Tech. Rep." }
FUNCTION {bbl.mthesis}{ "Master's thesis" }
FUNCTION {bbl.phdthesis}{ "Ph.D. dissertation" }
FUNCTION {bbl.st}{ "st" }
FUNCTION {bbl.nd}{ "nd" }
FUNCTION {bbl.rd}{ "rd" }
FUNCTION {bbl.th}{ "th" }
```

So you can make a copy of the file, calling it `IEEEtran-fr.bst` and change the constants (that is, what's between the quotes) as you please. Then you'll use

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran-fr}
```

Keep the copy in the same directory as your LaTeX document, or put it into a place where the TeX programs will find it, which might be

```
~/texmf/bibtex/bst/IEEEtran-fr.bst
```

on a GNU/Linux system with TeX Live or

```
~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst/IEEEtran-fr.bst
```

on Mac OS X with MacTeX.

Comment: Thanks you very much @egreg for the quick solution. I made a small typo: I was indeed using the `IEEEtran` style instead of the `IEEEtr`. Just didn't notice that section...